# BottomNavigation Material Design in Landscape mode

Tags: android

I am currently implementing a Bottom Navigation and i want to follow the Material Design Guidlines (https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html)

In Landscape I want to make the Bottom Navigation look like this:
[Design Guidline for Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFGwP.png)

I found a programmaticaly solution which works:

```
public void setLandscapeStyle(Context context) {
    BottomNavigationView view = layout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    BottomNavigationMenuView navigationMenuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    Menu menu = view.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) navigationMenuView.getChildAt(i);
        View itemBottomNavigation = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_navigation_item, navigationMenuView, false);
        ((ImageView) itemBottomNavigation.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(menu.getItem(i).getIcon());
        ((TextView) itemBottomNavigation.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(menu.getItem(i).getTitle());
        item.removeAllViews();
        item.addView(itemBottomNavigation);
    }
}
```

But it would be nice if i could avoid using this snippet and finding an solution in xml. I tried out a solution in xml with using an actionlayout for the menuItem of the Bottomnavigation but found out that Bottomnavigation is not supporting custom items.